# PubSub tutorial: Android device doesn't receive messages published by PC [solved]

Tags: ros, network-setup, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Dear ROS Community, I'm currently building a custom App to control my robot. Therefore I'm testing the PubSub tutorial provided by the android_core package: https://github.com/rosjava/android_core

Now if I connect my Android device to the ROS Master running on my PC and listen to the /chatter topic on my PC I receive the incoming "Hello World" messages sent by the talker node on my android device. However, if I publish a String message on my PC to the same topic it gets only displayed on the terminal running "rostopic echo /chatter" while the RosTextView on the android device only displays the messages published by the talker node but not what is published by my PC.

Running "~ rostopic info /chatter" delivers

```
Type: std_msgs/String 

Publishers:  
* /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker (http://192.168.1.102:57888/) 

Subscribers:  
* /android_gingerbread/ros_text_view (http://192.168.1.102:45315/)
```

Running ~ rosnode ping /android_gingerbread/ros_text_view  delivers

```
rosnode: node is [/android_gingerbread/ros_text_view] 
pinging /android_gingerbread/ros_text_view with a timeout of 3.0s 
xmlrpc reply from http://192.168.1.102:45315/   time=358.101130ms 
xmlrpc reply from http://192.168.1.102:45315/   time=124.948978ms 
xmlrpc reply from http://192.168.1.102:45315/   time=329.936981ms
```

So everything seems to be setup fine however the the RosTextView node doesn't react to messages published by my PC. It seems like a network issue.

Related posts suggested to create a publicly accessible nodeConfiguration via

```
NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().getHostAddress().toString(), masterUri);
```

which is already the case in the current pubsub tutorial.

Does somebody of you know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273655/pubsub-tutorial:-android-device-doesn%27t-receive-messages-published-by-pc-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [aurora18](https://answers.ros.org/users/32331/aurora18/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but try setting `ROS_IP=ip.of.your.pc` on your PC as an environment variable. It might be that the Android device is trying to resolve the hostname of your PC and is failing, hence cannot make a connection to the PC.

But it's just a guess/stab in the dark.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aurora18](https://answers.ros.org/users/32331/aurora18/) on 2017-10-20**:
Thank you so much!! Setting the ROS_IP solved my Problem! I tried that before but obviously changed to another terminal when publishing to /chatter where the environment variables weren't exported yet.
Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
You could either make sure you have a properly working DNS setup for all involved hosts, or add the `export ROS_IP=...` to your `.bashrc`. Or use a tool such as `ifdata` from the `moreutils` Ubuntu package.